# if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)); - unity console spamming

Tags: c#, console, unity-game-engine

i am actually learning to code a little bit in c# to make small games in unity5.
My problem is that when i am running the script the unity console is spamming "Up arrow pressed" and "Down arrow pressed" but i am not hitting anything.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow));
    {
        print("Up arrow pressed");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow));
    {
        print("Down arrow pressed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's "smpamming" because you have `;` after each `if` statement. That makes it an empty statement since:

```
{
    print("Up arrow pressed");
}
```

is simply a block of code and will execute even if the `if` statement is true or not. *Remove the semi-colon*.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        print("Up arrow pressed");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        print("Down arrow pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you what an embarrassing mistake sorry for that but i am into coding for maybe 1hour x).

Comment: That's fine. I really do suggest you learn basic C# stuff before working on Games. It will help you a lot. See [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting) C# tut for Unity.

Comment: Thank you i will definitely take a look ;)!

Comment: Yes, that is a classical beginners mistake. Control structures will either govern the next bracket, or everything to the next semikolon. Wichever comes first.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow));
```

Remove the ; at the end.
With the semicolon you basically describe that the if's executed block is empty. The following

```
{
    print ...
}
```

Is still a valid construct, as it defines a scope.